# Update or Insert based on key columns in Redshift

Tags: insert-update, duplicate-data, amazon-redshift

I am loading CSV files to Redshift daily. To handle duplicates i am loading the files to staging table and then using Update or Insert scripts based on key columns to load to the target table. Recently i found duplicate data in the target table unexpectedly.

I double checked my script and don't see any reason for having duplicates. Below are the Update and Insert script formats that i am using.

For Inserting:

```
      Insert into target (key1, key2, col3, col4)
      Select key1, key2, col3, col4 
      From stage s where not exists (select 1 from target t
                        where s.key1 = t.key1 and)
                        s.key2 = t.key2);
```

And for update:

```
      Update target Set
          key1=s.key1, key2=s.key2, col3=s.col3, col4=s.col4
      From stage s where target.key1=s.key1 and target.key2=s.key2;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this too.  The problem was in the insert...select... where the select itself produced duplicates.  One solution for us was to use a cursor (outside of Redshift) to run the select and insert one record at a time, but this proved to have performance issues.  Instead we now check for duplicates with an initial select

```
select key1,key2 from stage group by key1,key2 having count(*) > 1;
```

and stop the process if records are returned.